# access xampp localhost files when using http service

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, localhost, httpservice

i could not find a clear answer on how to access my own localhost for development environment to test http services.
So far i have tried doing http://localhost:8080/Folder/this.php and it goes www.localhost.com ??? i have checked that the access port is 80 in config file.

here is a code fragment that i wanted to implement on

```
function TMSSvc($http,$rootScope){
    this.loadBlogs= function(){
        $http.get("http://localhost:8080/webService/getBlogs.php").success(function(result){
              $rootScope.$broadcast("TMSApp.blogs",result);
          });
    }
}
```

Can you help me? I am a beginner in this . 
Thank You

Comment: tell your computer that the word localhost should point to 127.0.0.1 by editing the hosts file on your computer. Just add the line `127.0.0.1        localhost` then you should be able to type `localhost` in the address bar and it will direct to the localhost IP where xampp has control

Comment: @Wang'l Pakhin : check your virtual host setting.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows you need to go to the file:

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

If you are on Linux or Mac:

```
/etc/hosts (i.e. sudo nano /etc/hosts)
```

Then uncomment the line:

```
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
```

So it reads:

```
    127.0.0.1       localhost
```

You should then be able to access your local server using localhost.

Comment: for this to be a good answer, you should include the location on a Mac computer as well

Comment: _+1_ for multi-platform answer :D

Comment: Hello, it's directed me to GNU nano File: etchosts   and it's blank

Comment: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://127.0.0.1:8080/webServices/getBlogs.php. (Reason: CORS request failed).